# Is there a working C++ grammar file for ANTLR?

Tags: c++, antlr, lexer

Are there any existing C++ grammar files for ANTLR?

I'm looking to lex, not parse some C++ source code files.

I've looked on the [ANTLR grammar page](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) and it looks like there is one listed created by Sun Microsystems [here](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/tip/cnd.modelimpl/src/org/netbeans/modules/cnd/modelimpl/parser/cppparser.g).

However, it seems to be a generated Parser.

Can anyone point me to a C++ ANTLR lexer or grammar file?

Answer (score 1):

C++ parsers are *tough* to build.

I can't speak with experience about *using* ANTLR's C++ grammars. [Here I discuss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777924/120163) what I learned by reading the notes attached to the the one I did see at the ANTLR site; in essence, the author produced an incomplete grammar.  And that was for just C++98.   It has been awhile since I looked; there may be others.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has a [robust C++ front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html).

The lexer handles all the cruft for ANSI, GCC3, MS Visual Studio 2008, including large-precision floating point numbers, etc.

[EDIT: 12/2011. Now handles C++11 and OpenMP directives]

[EDIT:  3/2015: Now handles C++14 in both GCC and MS variants.
[See some parse trees here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393852/120163)]

Having "just" a parser is actually not very useful.  Above and beyond "just parsing", our front end will build ASTs, build accurate symbol tables (for C++, this is extremely hard to do), perform function-local flow analysis, and allow you to carry out program transformations, etc.  See [Life After Parsing](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html).

[EDIT: 5/2019: Now handles C++17 in ANSI, GCC and MS variants.  Does complete name and type resolution across compilation units.  Used to automate [large scale God-class refactoring/splitting](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/RefactoringTools/SplitInterface.html?site=StackOverflow) across systems of 3000 compilation units.]

Comment: I checked out your website, seems like you have some cool tools at reasonable prices, but your website could do with some work in both structure and look and feel.

Comment: @Andre: any constructive remarks you might make are welcome; we're always interested in improving. Please mail to "info@semanticdesigns.com".

Comment: How does your project compare to, say, [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), which does all you say, for free? I'm jesting, but still, interested in your answer!

Comment: If all you want is a parser for *preprocessed* C++, a tree builder for that C++, and non-composable procedural transforms on that AST, Clang is pretty good and free.   If you want to parse C++ *retaining* the preprocessor directives,  apply arbitrary strings of transforms done procedurally or with surface syntax rewrites (see http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSRewrites.html), or you want process many other languages this same way, DMS is more effective than Clang.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/WCRE05.pdf for a task  I've never seen anybody try with Clang.

Comment: For a more recent application of DMS which I think Clang would have a hard time, see discussion on automated refactoring of God classes:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56081753/120163