# Can I split code of class into one header and multiple source files?

Tags: c++

Is there a reasonable concern about splitting the source code of a class into different source files and one header file?

There is a class that needs to have a ton of functions. All of those functions shall be available for every instance of the object or its derived objects. Some of the especially complex functions could be grouped into "topics" (still they're not optional).

file ComplexObject.h

```
class ComplexObject {
  void BasicFunction1();
  void BasicFunction2();
  ...

  void SpecialFunctionA1();
  void SpecialFunctionA2();
  ...

  void SpecialFunctionB1();
  void SpecialFunctionB2();
  ...
}
```

The current single source code file ComplexObject.cpp has over 5000 lines of code. It is very hard to review. I would like to prevent having such a huge source file.

**1st considered Solution: incremental inheritance**

```
class ComplexObject { /* basic functions */ }
class SpecialObjectA : public ComplexObject { /* special functions A */ }
class SpecialObjectB : public SpecialObjectA { /* special functions B */ }
```

Would be OK. What bothers me about this solution is that it adds unnecessary complexity. If there were any situation were only SpecialObjectA is needed, I would chose this solution.

**2nd considered Solution: diamond shaped inheritance**

```
class ComplexObject { /* basic functions */ }
class SpecialObjectA : virtual public ComplexObject { /* special functions A */ }
class SpecialObjectB : virtual public ComplexObject { /* special functions B */ }
class FinalObject : public SpecialObjectA, SpecialObjectB {}
```

This solution adds even more unnecessary complexity. If there were situations that would require only SpecialObjectA or SpecialObjectB, this solution would of course be the obvious choice.

**3rd and favoured solution: Just split the source code into separate files**

I haven't seen this solution in any code I've reviewed. Nor do I recall any tutorial using this method. It seems to be a convenient choice for me.

file ComplexObject.cpp

```
#include ComplexObject.h
void ComplexObject::BasicFunction1() {...}
void ComplexObject::BasicFunction2() {...}
...
```

file ComplexObject_SpecialFunctionsA.cpp

```
#include ComplexObject.h
static void NeededOnlyBySpecialFunctionsA() {...}
...
void ComplexObject::SpecialFunctionA1() {...}
void ComplexObject::SpecialFunctionA2() {...}
...
```

file ComplexObject_SpecialFunctionsB.cpp

```
#include ComplexObject.h
static void NeededOnlyBySpecialFunctionsB() {...}
...
void ComplexObject::SpecialFunctionB1() {...}
void ComplexObject::SpecialFunctionB2() {...}
...
```

**4th possible solution: Leave the file as huge as it is**

Am I failing to see an even better option?

Comment: You'll need to consider what optimizations you can make here in terms of trade-offs. Is this a compile-time problem? A version control conflict issue? An impediment to iteration since the file is too big to work with?

Comment: `There is a class that needs to have a ton of functions. All of those functions shall be available for every instance of the object or its derived objects.` Are you really sure about that statements? Do all these functions modify object's state? Can they be moved into standalone utils? Can you use composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: @tadman Neither compile-time nor version control conflicts. So far it's just a pain to work with a file that huge. Logically it seems to make sense to split the implementation of the functions into "topics" or "groups" (sorry for lacking a better word).

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is yes, you could make a different cpp file for each function if you liked. Whether that is a good idea or not is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @IłyaBursov I have already taken that into consideration and of course I don't mind to reconsider it once more. It is a very good point you're bringing up. Please let's just for the sake of this question assume that they were necessary.

Comment: Not a dupe, but maybe some inspiration here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870377/how-do-you-refactor-a-god-class

Generally i'd look up 'god-object' or 'monolith' anti-patterns, as this is the vibe i get from that class.

Comment: I think you're ignoring Iłya's mention of composition here as a way of reducing complexity.

Comment: @tadman definitely not ignoring but possibly failing to understand. Could you please help me out and be a bit more detailed about it?

Comment: Answer to your question:  **yes**, I do that all the time.  I recommend **Large-scale C++ Software Design** by John Lakos as a very useful reference; it's a bit long in the tooth (from the mid 1990s), but still has a ton of useful and still applicable advice.

Comment: The approach here is usually "split this into *concerns*" which in practice means, like you said more informally, divide by "topic". When we talk about concerns we mean "code that relates to a particular function or feature" but usually with a specific focus, like data capture, processing, or display, where the separation here into separate stages helps provide clarity. Consistent terminology within your code base also helps considerably.

Comment: @tadman thank you, probably my way of describing/naming things led to misunderstandings and I apologize for that.

Comment: No apology necessary. A) You're identified a specific problem and explained your concerns. B) You're not using the correct terminology, but your communication is clear enough. C) Hope you can crack this nut!

Comment: The exemplary name i used for functions, probably led readers to think that they might be easily separated... I already put lots of thought into that and managed to change some of them into stand alone functions before posting here.
The project / the existing code base does not use the concept of composition over inheritance and although I see the general potential in it, I don't see it make a lot of difference in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting the source code into multiple files should not be the first thing to be taken into consideration. A file of that size is often an indicator of a conceptual problem.

Is the class as modular as it can be or could it be split into separate classes? The design principle of separating concerns should rather be applied on the class itself than on the file. As suggested in the comments, trying to move functions into standalone utils should also be done. Furthermore not only inheritance but also the concept of composition instead of it should be considered.

With all of that in mind, it is also possible to split the source code of a class into one header and multiple source files.

Comment: I don't want to answer my own question. But since nobody else does, I am writing a conclusion of the very helpful discussion in the comments above.